# python trying to generate all possible combinations of an array

Tags: python, arrays, list

> given two arrays I'm trying to get all the different combinations of the   arrays with no repeats of sequences and without using itertools. My problem  comes when I try to combine a 2 dimensional array with a 1 dimensional      array. given arrays [1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[2,3],[2,4] and [1,2,3,4] I want it to yield [1,2,3],[1,2,4],[1,3,4],[2,3,4]. currently it will produce [1,2,3], [1,2,4] and [1,3,4] but not [2,3,4] and I can't figure out why.

```
change_array = [1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[2,3],[2,4]
base_array = [1,2,3,4]
save_array = []

    
def candidate_generation2(change_array, base_array, save_array):
    current_iteration = []
    for x in range(0, len(change_array)):
        d = []
        for y in range(0, len(change_array[0])):
            d.append(change_array[x][y])        
        for z in range(x + 1, len(base_array)):
            e = d.copy()
            tag = 0
            for a in range(0, len(e)):
                if e[a] == base_array[z]:
                    tag = 1
            if tag == 0:
                e.append(base_array[z])
                save_array.append(e)
                current_iteration.append(e)
    chenge_array = current_iteration.copy()

candidate_generation2(change_array, base_array, save_array)    
print(save_array)
```

> thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

```
change_array = [1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[2,3],[2,4]
base_array = [1,2,3,4]

def candidate_generation2(change_array, base_array):
    for array in change_array:
        for value in base_array[base_array.index(array[-1])+1:]:
            yield array+[value]

for value in candidate_generation2(change_array, base_array):

    print(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension

```
change_array = [1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[2,3],[2,4]
base_array = [1,2,3,4]
save_array = []

[save_array.append(sorted(i+[j])) for j in base_array for i in change_array if j not in i and sorted(i+[j]) not in save_array] 

print(save_array)
```

**Output**:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]]
```